# NameError for Django Model

Tags: python, django

While trying to update the data stored and filter the objects of the model named Student I'm getting the following error:

> **NameError: name 'student' is not defined**

This is my Model.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date


# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    cover = models.TextField(max_length=100000, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=25000, blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Borrow(models.Model):
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

**Here is my views.py**

```
from library.models import Book, Category, Student, Borrow
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def student_edit(request):
    studentid = request.GET['sid'];
    first_name = request.GET['firstname'];
    last_name = request.GET['lastname'];
    depart = request.GET['department'];
    sectn = request.GET['section'];
    yr = request.GET['year']; 

    print(studentid);
    print(first_name);
    print(last_name);
    print(depart);
    print(sectn);
    print(yr);   
    student.objects.filter(student_id=studentid).update(firstname=first_name,       lastname=last_name,department=depart,section=sectn,year=yr)
```

**Please help me to solve this issue.**

Comment: `Student` starts with a *capital* letter., so `Student`, not `student`.

Comment: I would personally find it very troublesome if you every now and then get an error, since those are actually a lot harder to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo, your model name is 'Student' not 'student'

Comment: Thanku Sir....It was a little mistake but I am highly thankfull to you....you saved my time